# Warp raster using an arbitrary polygon

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

In Photoshop, is there a way to warp an irregular image selected area, but with controllable number of sides (let's say 8), by these boundary lines instead of a general rectangle around the selection (with help of Illustrator if necessary)?

[image: warp/transform/distort the blue area into red area (containing some image/pattern whose content is acceptable to be distorted)]

Comment: Yes. But without seeing the actual picture and usecase i can not describe a solution. I can not be expected to write a book on all cases and guessing game is not a good idea as you will just interject with no wont work in this situation because X. well either help us help you or expect vague answers.

Comment: Yeah. I study how to insert an image here :).

Comment: That is still just the same thing as a square. So do it as a square.

Comment: Nope, it is an 8-like shape, skewed at the right. The red area is a pattern, imagine a ground with leaves, for the exercise. It doesn't matters the content, I am looking for a way to distort this "8" instead of cropping.

Comment: Yes but you can treat it as 2 squares safely.

Comment: How? If I take some square area, I break the image during distortion, isn't it?

Comment: Depends on how you do it. All deformation methods could potentially ruin your internal structure. So all methods have the same problem uness you can describe how the internals need to deform.

Comment: It is OK to stretch/squeeze the contents, but not to break = discontinue it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45626/discussion-between-joojaa-and-mike).

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this method in Illustrator while doing a curved label:

- Place a raster, embedded, not linked.
- Convert the raster to a Symbol (F8).
- Put your "arbitrary polygon" above the symbol.
- Press Ctrl-Alt-C or choose the menu item Object: Envelope Distort: Make with Top Object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know about Transform-> warp and it's not giving satisfying result.

Only similar option I remember is a Puppet warp

Quick guide:
1.Select layer
2.go to edit->Puppet warp (triangular grid will appear on the object)
3. Add several anchors to object by clicking
4. Click and drag to move the anchor and portion of object

When you exit Puppet warp tool, anchors are lost

Hope this will help.
More info https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/warp-images-shapes-paths.html

Comment: Puppet warp is far too complex and removes parts of the original object at the corners. I can't control it.